# Pytest SQLAlchemy не подключается к БД на macos с использованием async_engine (eventlet)

Tags: python-3.x, macos, sqlalchemy, pytest, fastapi

В FastApi приложении, при попытке запуска pytest тестов на macos 13, при использовании `sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.create_async_engine` не происходит подключение к бд в Docker контейнере. Ошибка:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'")
```

root cause error:

```
KeyError: '11 is not registered'
```

Настройка соединения верная, БД доступна, все порты настроены.
На Linux OS тот-же проект запускается и работает без проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для меня проблема решилась удалением транзитивно установленного пакета `eventlet`.

```
pip unsinstall eventlet
```

В указанной конфигурации на mac `eventlet` и генерирует ошибку
`KeyError: '11 is not registered'`